# Time circle jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, time

I have an issue in jQuery time circle stop watch. I have download this plugin from here: http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/

Here the same issue I am facing in given demo for this plugin. I have added this code

```
      <h2>Time in ascending order</h2>
        <div id="CountDownTimer" style="width: 1000px; height: 250px;"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-success startTimer">Start Timer</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger stopTimer">Stop Timer</button>
      <hr>
```

I have just removed this attribute(`data-timer="900"`) from `div` that have `id="CountDownTimer"`. Just because i want time in ascending order like 1,2,3 etc

I have two buttons "start" and "stop". When I click on start it's working fine when I stop that and again start it not running from where I stop that, time is running in backend.

I want when I click on start button after stop it should start time where I STOP THAT.

I am facing the same issue in demo after removing this attribute `data-timer="900"`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/TimeCircles.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/TimeCircles.css" />
     </head>
   <body>
     <div class="container">
        <h1>TimeCircle examples</h1>
        <h2>Time until 2014</h2>
        <div id="DateCountdown" data-date="2014-01-01 00:00:00" style="width: 500px; height: 125px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #E0E8EF"></div>
        <div style="padding: 10px;">
            <input type="date" id="date" value="2014-01-01">
            <input type="time" id="time" value="00:00">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h2>I am using this one</h2>
        <div id="CountDownTimer" style="width: 1000px; height: 250px;"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-success startTimer">Start Timer</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger stopTimer">Stop Timer</button>
        <hr>
        <h2>Time since page was opened</h2>
        <div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block fadeIn">Fade in</button><br>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block fadeOut">Fade out</button>
            </div>
            <div id="PageOpenTimer" style="width: 500px; height: 125px; float: left"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#DateCountdown").TimeCircles();
        $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false } }});
        $("#PageOpenTimer").TimeCircles();

        var updateTime = function(){
            var date = $("#date").val();
            var time = $("#time").val();
            var datetime = date + ' ' + time + ':00';
            $("#DateCountdown").data('date', datetime).TimeCircles().start();
        }
        $("#date").change(updateTime).keyup(updateTime);
        $("#time").change(updateTime).keyup(updateTime);

        // Start and stop are methods applied on the public TimeCircles instance
        $(".startTimer").click(function() {
            $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles().start();
        });
        $(".stopTimer").click(function() {
            $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles().stop();
        });

        // Fade in and fade out are examples of how chaining can be done with TimeCircles
        $(".fadeIn").click(function() {
            $("#PageOpenTimer").fadeIn();
        });
        $(".fadeOut").click(function() {
            $("#PageOpenTimer").fadeOut();
        });

    </script>       
</body>
```

Comment: One demo would be more helpful

Comment: But i want along with start and stop button,same issue with one deom

Comment: I can't understand where the problem is without demo

Comment: fiddled his code: http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/GTS24/

Comment: I have done with this issue please let me know i can reset timer when it min = 1

Comment: I just want it to play only for one min in asecending order like 1sec 2 3 4 .......................................60 sec then reset

Answer (score 0):

I know its late...but i think it will work

```
 $(".stoptimer").click(function(){ $("#countdowntimer").TimeCircles().stop(); });
  $(".starttimer").click(function(){ $("#countdowntimer").TimeCircles().start(); });
```